# How to test wash_out controller with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, rspec

I have implemented a Rails controller with the [wash_out](https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out) gem.

My controller look like this:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  include WashOut::SOAP

  soap_action "int_to_string",
              :args   => :integer,
              :return => :string
  def int_to_string
    render :soap => params[:value].to_s
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  wash_out :test
end
```

I am not sure how I can test this controller with Rspec.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In this link you can find a good aproach

http://blog.johnsonch.com/2013/04/18/rails-3-soap-and-testing-oh-my/

The aproach is:

- Create a client with savonrb gem
- compare the result in your test

Answer (score 0):

you can spec the default wsdl route with something like:

```
 require "spec_helper"

describe MywsdlController do
  describe "routing" do

    it "mywsdl/wsdl route to mywsdl#_generate_wsdl" do 
      get("/mywsdl/wsdl").should route_to("mywsdl#_generate_wsdl")
    end

  end
end
```

then Id suggest to have a soap dir within spec one and a spec file per available service so  you can init soap client before:each with testing params, that might give you a spec scenario.